# HTMLString Serialized as string, encoded in json

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Simply I want to have a property in my object serialized as a string instead of HtmlString(which it is).

The reasoning here is that the object is serialized in json, and the toString function is not returning the string contents of the object but rather '[object Object]'.

Alternatively, would it be possible to label the property as [Non-Serializable] and expose another property in its stead as the serializable version?

Thanks in advance

Edit: 
Example Code:

```
[Serializable]
public MyObject 
{
    public int id= 0;
    public string name = "myName";
    public HtmlString WishIWasAString = new HtmlString("notAString");
    public string fakeHtmlString
    {
        get { return WishIWasAString.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Example Json:

```
{
  id: 0, 
  name: 'myName'
  wishIWasAString: {}
  fakeHtmlString: 'notAString'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="type/javascript">
    var fooProperty = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Foo));
</script>
```

or if you wanted to JSON serialize your entire model into a javascript variable:

```
<script type="type/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    alert(model.Foo.Bar);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i think i may have failed to explain the question as clearly as i had hoped.  I've added example code and the output it produces to help clarify the issue.  Ideally i could produce the fakeHtmlString from the HtmlString instead of a hacked property.

Comment: @Highstead, may I ask why would you be using the `HtmlString` type on your view model?

Comment: I suppose i don't necessarily NEED to use the html string, and could just escape the string at run-time.  But the data it represents in the backend is effectively HtmlString.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to your question.
Use this class:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public MyObject 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HtmlString MyHtmlContent { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "MyHtmlContent")]
    private string serializedMyHtmlContent
    {
        get { return this.MyHtmlContent == null ? null : MyHtmlContent .ToString(); }
    }
}
```

You will obtain this JSON:

```
{
    Id: 1234,
    Name: "Chris",
    MyHtmlContent: "<p>Hello word</p>"
}
```